# Android Studio use native executable and ship them inside the apk

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, assets

I'm trying to use some executables inside my app. This executable is C++ based (with images and logs as output), there may be other ways to use C++ code, but in this specific context, it might be the best to use it as an executable which only needs arguments. (NDK f.e. will be too much changing of the used library and I'm hoping there may be a way to parallelize this process some days)

My research showed that some other people were looking for similar problems. It seems that the best way was to add these external programs inside the assets folder (app/src/main/assets). That is what I did, but now I'm not quite sure how to get my data inside the assets folder. Some posting said that these files have to be extracted in another folder to get them work.

So I tried this method:
[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard) (result: app shutdown)

I would like to add some code, but there isn't much for now. As I already told my executable should be inside assets and its name is f.e. exec, I also named it libexec.so, because I read somewhere that you have to name these files like lib"...".so to get them extracted. In general, my aim is to use this executable like:
`data/exec`

Now to my questions:

1. How can I get access my assets files?
2. Or should I use another folder instead of assets, will it be easier to use? How could I add an external executable there?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I managed to get it work through:
https://github.com/flipagram/android-assetcopier

I just had to change something: 
Example was: 
`File destDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

I've changed it to: `File destDir = (MainActivity.this).getFilesDir();` - so there is no problem with permissions (I guess).

But be aware: Copying is successful, but I did not manage to run the program successfully. Maybe the whole process will get killed through a security manager or something else won't work.